# Vis.js How to show only children/descendents of selected node?

Tags: javascript, python, networkx, vis.js, vis.js-network

If not posible with vis.js, I could do the entire thing on something else. But this functionality is crucial. So, show everything if nothing selected; show only children (with the "from" arrow) of some node if that node is selected. Or to select the node in some list, or type it somewhere.
https://codepen.io/andre-fr-silva/pen/ZEBPpqK

```
var container = document.getElementById("mynetwork");
var data = {
  nodes: nodes,
  edges: edges,
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Direct Decendents

This can be achieved using the select event defined in the documentation [here](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/#Events) in combination with the hidden property on nodes defined [here](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/nodes.html). You can update the data in the DataSet, the network will then display the updates. In summary the logic I would suggest is to:

1. If no nodes are selected

   1. Unhide all nodes
2. If one or more nodes are selected

   1. Hide all nodes
   2. Display the selected nodes
   3. Display nodes connected from the selected node

The following implements this logic.

```js
network.on('select', function (properties) {
  // Define an array of nodes ot update, this is quicker than
  // updating each node individually
  let nodesToUpdate = [];
  
  // If no nodes are selected, unhide all hidden nodes
  if(properties.nodes.length === 0){
    // Populate array with list of nodes to unhide
    data.nodes.forEach(node => {
      if(node.hidden){ 
        nodesToUpdate.push({id:node.id, hidden: false});
      }
    });
    
    // Update nodes and return
    data.nodes.update(nodesToUpdate);
    return;
  }
    
  // One or more nodes are selected
  // Populate array with list of all nodes, hiding them
  data.nodes.forEach(node => {
    nodesToUpdate.push({id:node.id, hidden: true});
  });

  // Pouplate array with list of selected and connected nodes to unhide
  // Note: Nodes will already exist in the array, but these later updates
  //       will overwrite the earlier ones.
  properties.nodes.forEach(node => {
    // Add selected node
    nodesToUpdate.push({id:node, hidden:false});
    
    // Add connected nodes to the selected node
    data.edges.forEach(edge => {
      // Unhide if connected from selected node and connected node exists
      if(edge.from === node && data.nodes.get(edge.to)){
        nodesToUpdate.push({id:edge.to, hidden: false});
      }
    });
  }); 
  
  // Submit updates to hide/unhide nodes
  data.nodes.update(nodesToUpdate);
});
```

Please note this could be optimised further, removing or updating items in the `nodesToUpdate` array instead of duplicating them.

#### All Decendents

A similar approach can be used to show all dependents. Using recursion is the easiset way to achieve this, with checks to make sure the code doesn't get caught in am endless loop (if one exists in the network). In the sample code below a new function named `addChildNodes` is declared that is called recursively to add each nodes children as the edges are followed.

```js
function addChildNodes(nodesToUpdate, node){
  // Add child nodes for the passed node
  // Loop around all edges
  data.edges.forEach(edge => {
    // Check if connected from the passed node and connected node exists
    if(edge.from === node.id && data.nodes.get(edge.to)){
      // Find the child node in the update array
      let childNode = nodesToUpdate.find(node => node.id === edge.to);
    
      // Check if the child node is hidden
      // If the node is not hidden then it's already been processed
      // Don't process it again otherwise could get caught in a loop
      if(childNode.hidden){     
        // Node is currently hidden, therefore hasn't been processed yet
        // Set node to be displayed
        childNode.hidden = false;
        
        // Recursive call to function to process its children
        addChildNodes(nodesToUpdate, childNode);
      }
    }
  });
}

network.on('select', function (properties) {
  // Define an array of nodes ot update, this is quicker than
  // updating each node individually
  let nodesToUpdate = [];
  
  // If no nodes are selected, unhide all hidden nodes
  if(properties.nodes.length === 0){
    // Populate array with list of nodes to unhide
    data.nodes.forEach(node => {
      if(node.hidden){ 
        nodesToUpdate.push({id:node.id, hidden: false});
      }
    });
    
    // Update nodes and return
    data.nodes.update(nodesToUpdate);
    return;
  }
    
  // One or more nodes are selected
  // Populate array with list of all nodes, hiding them
  data.nodes.forEach(node => {
    nodesToUpdate.push({id:node.id, hidden: true});
  });

  // Update the arra setting list of selected and connected nodes to unhide
  properties.nodes.forEach(nodeId => {
    // Find the selected node in the array
    let node = nodesToUpdate.find(node => node.id === nodeId);
    
    // Update selected node to be displayed
    node.hidden = false;
  
    // Call recursive function to add all dependents
    addChildNodes(nodesToUpdate, node);
  }); 
  
  // Submit updates to hide/unhide nodes
  data.nodes.update(nodesToUpdate);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Just one small further question. This catches the immediate descendants only. In the case of the "directed arrow" ones, how can I iterate down so that it does it to all descendants (children of children...) everytime there is still an "arrow" to another node? Should I iterate your if clause inside? The overall goal here is to basically give anatomy students a quick way to see everything that is innervated by some nerve.

Comment: Glad I could help. I've updated the answer with an example for all decendents. It uses recursion to follow each of the edges, updating the nodes as it goes.

Comment: Boom, worked and nicely commented. I'll have to buy you a beer, man. If you ever came to the nice weather of Portugal, shout out.

Comment: Very glad to hear that!

Comment: There's no `update` method on `vis.Data.nodes`. I'm using TS.

Comment: @Abhijit - I'd check you are using a dataset, and post a new question if it's still not working. In the example above the network is initiated using `var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);` where `data` is an object containing the nodes and edges. The nodes and edges are DataSet objects created using `new vis.DataSet([...])`. The methods available on DataSet including the update method can be seen at https://visjs.github.io/vis-data/data/dataset.html#Methods

Comment: Yes, my bad. That indeed solved it. Thanks.